# How to reposition window in SSH session? I am logging into a Linux machine from a Mac machine

Tags: linux, ssh, mac, terminal

I am using a Mac with XQuartz to display an X application running on a remote CentOS machine.

I'm trying to reposition the window from the remote machine using my keyboard, as it opens in such a way as to hide the top of the window and the menu. So, I can't drag it around with the mouse.

It's been suggested that I simply hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag it, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, but neither of these have worked.

Any suggestions for moving the window with the keyboard, or perhaps controlling its position on my screen when it first opens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your remote machine, you could try starting the X application with a `-geometry` parameter, e.g.

```sh
xeyes -geometry 1000x500-20-20
```

Although it's pretty straightforward, you can consult some [X windows documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/7/x) for details on what this parameter is. (And, wow, this took me way back, man!)

For moving the window with the mouse, you can left-click on the X application window's title bar (if any) to drag the window around the screen. Or you can right-click in the window's interior.

If you're trying to do the latter with your Mac's touchpad, it will help if you enable three button mouse emulation in XQuartz preferences. Then, you just press <kbd>Alt</kbd> (<kbd>Option</kbd>) for right-clicking.

[image: XQuartz preferences window]

Comment: Thanks, this is so helpful!  One thing, though - it looks like Spyder, the application I'm trying to start from the command line, does not accept command line arguments like a typical X application does (so it doesn't recognize "-display" or "-geometry".  any way to hack this so it works?

Comment: Bah, to heck with it, I just ran "spyder --reset", and this put the window back in its default position.  Who needs to learn anything, anyway!?